# How to hint a reactive variable that it has changed?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have an object "Employee".

```
export interface Employee {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

To change it, I developed the "My Editor" component.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { Employee } from "./DataType";
import MyEditor from "./MyEditor.vue";

const myData = ref<Employee>({ name: "Mike", age: 31 });
</script>
<template>
  {{ myData }}
  <br />
  <MyEditor v-model:data="myData" />
  <br />
  <MyEditor :data="myData" @update:data="myData = Object.assign({}, $event)" />
</template>
```

In it, I change the values ​​​​of the fields, and then by pressing the ok button, I send the changed data to the parent.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { Employee } from "./DataType";

const props = defineProps<{
  data: Employee;
}>();
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "update:data", value: Employee): void;
}>();
const clonedData = Object.assign({}, props.data);
</script>
<template>
  <input v-model="clonedData.name" />
  <br />
  <button @click="emit('update:data', clonedData)">Ok</button>
</template>
```

In a parent component, reactivity will only work if the object itself is changed, not its properties. that is, instead of

> v-model:data="myData"

have to do

> :data="myData" @update:data="myData = Object.assign({}, $event)"

And this is not very aesthetically pleasing, are there other options?

[playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)